# C#-Send selected commands from ListBox to Arduino

Tags: c#, arduino, listbox, serial-port

How can I output code under method of listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged in C# to arduino. I have the following codes:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string regreg = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();   

    if (regreg == "LDA")          
        serialPort1.WriteLine("LDA");            
    else if (regreg == "ADD")           
        serialPort1.WriteLine("ADD");            
    else if (regreg == "SUB")            
        serialPort1.WriteLine("SUB");            
    else if (regreg == "HLT")            
        serialPort1.WriteLine("HLT");            
    else if (regreg == "OUT")            
        serialPort1.WriteLine("OUT");            
}
```

I uses to output those command using textbox and a button, and it works. The LEDs connected to the arduino lights up. The codes are as follows:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "LDA")
        serialPort1.WriteLine("LDA");
    else if (textBox1.Text == "ADD")
        serialPort1.WriteLine("ADD");
    else if (textBox1.Text == "SUB")
        serialPort1.WriteLine("SUB");
    else if (textBox1.Text == "HLT")
        serialPort1.WriteLine("HLT");
    else if (textBox1.Text == "OUT")
        serialPort1.WriteLine("OUT");      
}
```

Now the problem is that, every time I changed my selected index, nothing happens on LEDs connected to arduino even though I put the code under the event `SelectedIndexChanged` of `ListBox`.

The arduino code for reference:

```
int m;              //This will be received thru the serial Port.
String Mnemonic="";
int ledPin1 = 2;
int ledPin2 = 3;
int ledPin3 = 5;
int ledPin4 = 6;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); //Set Baud Rate of Serial

    pinMode(ledPin1,OUTPUT);   
    pinMode(ledPin2,OUTPUT);         
    pinMode(ledPin3,OUTPUT);   
    pinMode(ledPin4,OUTPUT);

}

void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available()>0)   //Check if serial port is open.
    //get the number of bytes available for reading
    {   
        m=Serial.read();   //Read Incoming char from the PC.
        Mnemonic += (char)m;
        if (Mnemonic=="LDA")
        {
            digitalWrite(ledPin1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(ledPin2,LOW);
            digitalWrite(ledPin3,LOW);
            digitalWrite(ledPin4,HIGH);
        }
        else if (Mnemonic=="ADD")
        {
            digitalWrite(ledPin1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(ledPin2,LOW);
            digitalWrite(ledPin3,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(ledPin4,LOW);
        }
        else if (Mnemonic=="SUB")
        {
            digitalWrite(ledPin1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(ledPin2,LOW);
            digitalWrite(ledPin3,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(ledPin4,HIGH);
        }
        else if (Mnemonic=="HLT")
        {
            digitalWrite(ledPin1,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(ledPin2,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(ledPin3,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(ledPin4,LOW);
        }    
        else if (Mnemonic=="OUT")
        {  
            digitalWrite(ledPin1,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(ledPin2,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(ledPin3,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(ledPin4,HIGH);

        }  
        if(m==10) Mnemonic = "";
       Serial.flush();//removed any buffered incoming serial data
    }
}
```

PS. I already check the COM ports and its all connected since the textbox and button works. You can edit my title as I don't know what to put.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried the debugger and did you watched what was going on in that listbox method?

Comment: Do you have another process running in the background that overwrites the commands that you send from the `ListBox` ? When you set a breakpoint in `string regreg = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); ` what value do you get for `regreg` when you change the selection?